# Do probability wave function moves or it is just sitting there until it interacts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, wavefunction-collapse

Imagine an electron is emitted from a source, at this moment the probability wave function of the electron appears... then how come the same electron have to take some time to reach the target such as the screen? I like to neglect the quantum eraser experiment for now since it is disturbing.

Btw Merry Xmas! wishlist for Santa... a XL Hadron Collider ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wavefunction is the solution of a quantum mechanical equation that is a function, in this case, of (x,y,z,t) for the given boundary conditions. $Ψ^*Ψ$ is the probability of finding the electron at a given (x,y,z,t). It is a solution for all space time, so this answers your:

> then how come the same electron have to take some time

the time is within the wavefunction's mathematical form.

If  the boundary conditions change by the electron interacting, then  a new wavefunction has to be calculated modeling the interaction.